# Google App Engine and Wordpress set up error - Windows 7 professional

Tags: php, wordpress, google-app-engine, app.yaml

I'm trying to set up Google App Engine and Wordpress version 3.8 according to instruction at https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/wordpress

But when I run `$ APP_ENGINE_SDK_PATH/dev_appserver.py APPLICATION_DIRECTORY` I have got the error

> Unable to assign value 'wordpress/.*.(htm|html|css|js)$' to attribute
>   'upload:' value 'wordpress/.*.(htm|html|css|js)$' for upload does not
>   match expression '^(?:(?!\^).*(?!\$).)$' in app.yaml in line 9, column
>   11

Here is my app.yaml file's content:

```
application: thangvmwordpressdemo
version: 1
runtime: php
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /(.*\.(htm|html|css|js))$
  static_files: wordpress/\1
  upload: wordpress/.*\.(htm|html|css|js)$
  application_readable: true

- url: /wp-content/(.*\.(ico|jpg|png|gif))$
  static_files: wordpress/wp-content/\1
  upload: wordpress/wp-content/.*\.(ico|jpg|png|gif)$
  application_readable: true

- url: /(.*\.(ico|jpg|png|gif))$
  static_files: wordpress/\1
  upload: wordpress/.*\.(ico|jpg|png|gif)$

- url: /wp-admin/(.+)
  script: wordpress/wp-admin/\1
  secure: always

- url: /wp-admin/
  script: wordpress/wp-admin/index.php
  secure: always

- url: /wp-login.php
  script: wordpress/wp-login.php
  secure: always

- url: /wp-cron.php
  script: wordpress/wp-cron.php
  login: admin

- url: /xmlrpc.php
  script: wordpress/xmlrpc.php

- url: /wp-(.+).php
  script: wordpress/wp-\1.php

- url: /(.+)?/?
  script: wordpress/index.php
```

Can you have me solve this problem?
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 7):

As of 19 Jan 2014 that article doesn´t work with current Google App Engine for PHP SDK v1.8.9 (Windows). The problem is the final regex ending ($) of the handlers.upload attribute. I´m not sure why this has happened and when it will get fixed, however, you can try any of the following workarounds:

You have to either remove it:

```
handlers:
- url: /.*\.(htm|html|css|js)
  static_files: wordpress/\1
  upload: wordpress/.*\.(htm|html|css|js)
  application_readable: true
```

or use the semantically equivalent (to the faulty one):

```
handlers:
- url: /.*\.(htm|html|css|js)
  static_files: wordpress/\1
  upload: wordpress/.*\.(htm$|html$|css$|js$)
  application_readable: true
```

Cheers !!

Answer (score 1):

The documentation was recently update to reflect changes made in the regex validation. The validation is done both by the SDK on the client side and on the server side (app engine). Please make sure you are using the 1.8.9 SDK (current), otherwise regex ending in $ will not work.

Answer (score 0):

+1 to boombatower's comments; you might have better luck using the GitHub "Starter Project" for WordPress that we posted here: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-php-wordpress-starter-project

That article is tough to follow because there is such a difference between going through all those steps and just cloining a git project and getting on with it, and it's also updated less frequently because the git project is "crowdsourced" among several Googlers while the article is written by one writer with many other priorities.

Here's the app.yaml file from that project, for comparison:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-php-wordpress-starter-project/blob/master/app.yaml

Comment: The starter project on github still raise the same error with SDK 1.8.9. ASBH's answer is my life saver :)

Answer (score 0):

Also had this problem. You need to download the latest version of the appengine SDK for PHP. It's at 1.9.2 now. You can maintain separate versions if you still need the older version.