# google app engine wordpress update failure

Tags: python, wordpress, google-app-engine

I have come across a problem with the app.yaml setup for the installation of wordpress in GAE following this guide: https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/wordpress

Using the guide, I copied the app.yaml (I also used the github project: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-php-wordpress-starter-project to check that my copy/paste was ok).

Whilst the test using dev_appserver.py works fine, the upload whinges with the message:

```
03:08 PM Getting current resource limits.
03:08 PM Scanning files on local disk.
03:08 PM Scanned 500 files.
03:08 PM Scanned 1000 files.
Error 400: --- begin server output ---
Error when loading application configuration:
Unable to assign value '__static__/wordpress/.*\.(htm|html|css|js)$' to attribute 'upload':
Value '__static__/wordpress/.*\.(htm|html|css|js)$' for upload does not match expression '^(?:(?!\^).*(?!\$).)$'
--- end server output ---
```

I am using the PHP SDK v1.8.9. My app.yaml is as follows:

```
application: blah-de-blah
version: wp
runtime: php
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /(.*\.(htm|html|css|js))$
  static_files: wordpress/\1
  upload: wordpress/.*\.(htm|html|css|js)$
  application_readable: true

- url: /wp-content/(.*\.(ico|jpg|png|gif))$
  static_files: wordpress/wp-content/\1
  upload: wordpress/wp-content/.*\.(ico|jpg|png|gif)$
  application_readable: true

- url: /(.*\.(ico|jpg|png|gif))$
  static_files: wordpress/\1
  upload: wordpress/.*\.(ico|jpg|png|gif)$

- url: /wp-admin/(.+)
  script: wordpress/wp-admin/\1
  secure: always

- url: /wp-admin/
  script: wordpress/wp-admin/index.php
  secure: always

- url: /wp-login.php
  script: wordpress/wp-login.php
  secure: always

- url: /wp-cron.php
  script: wordpress/wp-cron.php
  login: admin

- url: /xmlrpc.php
  script: wordpress/xmlrpc.php

- url: /wp-(.+).php
  script: wordpress/wp-\1.php

- url: /(.+)?/?
  script: wordpress/index.php
```

Something is up with the file type selector regex, but I'm not sure how to fix it. Someone came across it here: [Google App Engine and Wordpress set up error - Windows 7 professional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21148567/google-app-engine-and-wordpress-set-up-error-windows-7-professional) but it's still not fixed.

Does anyone have any light to shed on the subject?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok - I fixed it. The app.yaml needed modifying.

I think the instructions on the guide are a bit misleading - maybe something is out of date?

Here is my fixed app.yaml:

```
application: pooper-scooper-117 
version: wp
runtime: php
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /(.*\.(htm$|html$|css$|js$))
  static_files: wordpress/\1
  upload: wordpress/.*\.(htm$|html$|css$|js$)
  application_readable: true

- url: /wp-content/(.*\.(ico$|jpg$|png$|gif$))
  static_files: wordpress/wp-content/\1
  upload: wordpress/wp-content/.*\.(ico$|jpg$|png$|gif$)
  application_readable: true

- url: /(.*\.(ico$|jpg$|png$|gif$))
  static_files: wordpress/\1
  upload: wordpress/.*\.(ico$|jpg$|png$|gif$)

- url: /wp-admin/(.+)
  script: wordpress/wp-admin/\1
  secure: always

- url: /wp-admin/
  script: wordpress/wp-admin/index.php
  secure: always

- url: /wp-login.php
  script: wordpress/wp-login.php
  secure: always

- url: /wp-cron.php
  script: wordpress/wp-cron.php
  login: admin

- url: /xmlrpc.php
  script: wordpress/xmlrpc.php

- url: /wp-(.+).php
  script: wordpress/wp-\1.php

- url: /(.+)?/?
  script: wordpress/index.php
```

Answer (score 0):

you shouldn't have to modify the app.yaml or submit a pull request(unless it's to change the documentation). Instead you need to get the latest version of the appengine SDK for PHP. As of mid January older versions won't work.

Comment: nice vague answer there..... The SDK was the latest at that time for MacOSX. What platform were you using?

Comment: Apologies, I assumed latest would imply getting the most recent version to date. I'm using ubuntu - I upgraded from 1.8.9 to 1.9.2 and everything worked fine afterwards